Mid 90s movie set in prison where two men are friends and one tries to break out
I watched this movie around 1995-96. A few tenuous details that I remember:

It is about prison and two guys are friends.
One guy is very nice and maintains a good reputation throughout the movie.
Same guy tries to break prison in the end.

I think this movie was released sometime ago, not so old (80's or 90's). 

I think the movie you are trying to remember is 1994's Shawshank Redemption.
It is about a man (played by Tim Robbins) who is wrongly convicted for a murder he didn't commit. In prison he befriends another inmate (played by Morgan Freeman) and works himself into the favour of the prison director. Till one day after many years in prison he breaks free and it is revealed that he was working on his escape all the time.

Wondering if you're thinking of Tango and Cash.  

Ray Tango and Gabriel Cash are narcotics detectives who, while both
  being extremely successful, can't stand each other. Crime Lord Yves
  Perret, furious at the loss of income that Tango and Cash have caused
  him, frames the two for murder. Caught with the murder weapon on the
  scene of the crime, the two have alibi. Thrown into prison with most
  of the criminals they helped convict, it appears that they are going
  to have to trust each other if they are to clear their names and catch
  the evil Perret.


Have not you noticed that user already got his answer?
